# How to know which frames are on top (aka after tkraise)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a GUI with Tkinter and need to know which frame is on top so one of the lowered ones does not enter one of its loop and changes some settings.

I have already tried with

`self.tk.eval('frame stackorder '+str(self.frames["StartPage"])+' isabove '+str(self.frames["Wallpaper"]))=='1'`

self being my root (its a class) and get this error

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name "stackorder"
```

also

```
self.tk.eval('wm stackorder '+str(self.frames["StartPage"])
```

gives me the this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: window ".!frame.!startpage" isn't a top-level window
```

This is the way I create and change between frames

```
self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
```

I took the way to change frame from here ([Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter)) but dont know how to know which one is on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably keep a reference to the visible frame, so you can access it:

```
class App(tk.Tk()):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self.visible_frame = "StartPage"
        ...

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
        self.visible_frame = page_name
```

Comment: Thanks I dont know how I didn´t thought of that.

Comment: Very welcomed - frankly, I think tkinter ought to have a method to query the visible frame.